# How to add new row to dataTables from custom styles HTML string

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I am trying to add a row to an existing datatables table by returning a custom styled html string and using that string to populate the new row.

The table I am using is as follows

```
<table class="table table-striped shadow-sm data-table data-table-auto-init"
   id="table"
   data-table-columns="dropdown1,dropdown2,dropdown3,Input1,Input2,Input3,{HTML},{HTML2}"      
   />
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">dropdown1</th>
        <th scope="col">dropdown2</th>
        <th scope="col">dropdown3</th>
        <th scope="col">Input1</th>
        <th scope="col">Input2</th>
        <th scope="col">Input3</th>
        <th></th>                        
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    @{
        if (Model.rows != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                
                <partial name="../RowsTable" model="@Model.Rows[i]"/>
            }
        }
        else
        {
           
            var rowModel = new RowModel
            {
                dropdown1 = Model.Dropdown1,
                dropdown2 = Model.Dropdown2,
                dropdown3 = Model.Dropdown3
            };
             <partial name="../RowsTable" model="@rowModel"/>
        }
    }
</tbody>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
```

I am currently having to do some processing stuff so am going to the server side when the AddRow button is clicked and returning the html generated by the model through some custom RazorViewEngine code.

The HTML that is returned is as follows;

```
<tr>
<td>
    <select id="dropdown1" class="form-select shadow-sm" name="dropdown1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">ITEM1</option>
        <option value="2">ITEM2</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select id="dropdown2" class="form-select shadow-sm" name="dropdown2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">ITEM1</option>
        <option value="2">ITEM2</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select id="dropdown3" class="form-select shadow-sm" name="dropdown3">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">ITEM1</option>
        <option value="2">ITEM2</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td> <input id="Input1" class="form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm" type="text" name="Input1" value=""></td>
<td> <input id="Input2" class="form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm" type="text" name="Input2" value=""></td>
<td> <input id="Input3" class="form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm" type="text" name="Input3" value=""></td>

<td>
    <button id="AddRowButton" type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            onclick="addTableRow(this)"
                                >
        <i class="fas fa-regular fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</td> 
<td>
    <button id="DeleteRowButton" type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            onclick="deleteTableRow(this)">
        <i class="fas fa-regular fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>
</td>
```

I am then using a post fetch method to try and add this html string to a new row in the DataTable. The code I am using is;

```
$("#table").dataTable().fnAddData(data.HTMLString)
```

But sadly with this the DataTable is throwing the following error;

```
DataTables warning: table id=table- Requested unknown parameter 'dropdown1' for row 1, column 0.
```

Just wondering if anyone would know the correct approach for this method of adding rows to a dataTable, I understand it is probably a very niche way of manipulating the data but user requirements have my hands kind of tied.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you confirm that the server response is formatted as an array of HTML strings, each representing a cell in the new row?

Comment: Try using the [row.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) API wrapping the string in a jQuery object, like this example:
https://live.datatables.net/musutuce/1/edit